# Non-computable function having computable values on a dense set of computable arguments

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, algorithms, computability

A *rational complex* number is a complex number whose both real and imaginary parts are rational numbers. Note that a rational complex number is a finitary object that can be an input or an output of an algorithm.

A sequence of rational complex numbers is *computable* if there is an algorithm that given a positive integer index $k$ as an input, returns the corresponding element of the sequence.

A complex number $z$ is *computable* if there is a computable sequence of rational complex numbers that converges to $z$.

A function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is *computable* if there is an algorithm $P$ with the following property: for each (not necessarily computable) sequence of rational complex numbers $\{q_1,q_2,...\}$ that converges to a complex number $z$, when the algorithm $P$ is given the sequence $\{q_1,q_2,...\}$ as an input, it generates an infinite sequence of rational complex numbers $\{p_1,p_2,...\}$ that converges to $f(z)$. (More precisely, if $P$ is given an access to an oracle that can tell elements $q_m$ by their index $m$, and given a positive integer index $k$ as an input, it generates a rational complex number $p_k$; the sequence $\{p_1,p_2,...\}$ of those outputs converges to $f(z)$).

A function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is *pointwise computable on a dense set* if there exists a set of complex numbers $S$ dense in $\mathbb C$, such that every $z\in S$ is computable, and the corresponding function value $f(z)$ is computable.

> 1. Is there a **continuous** function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ that is pointwise computable on a dense set but not computable?
> 2. Is there an **analytic** function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ that is pointwise computable on a dense set but not computable?

Comment: As written, 1 has a trivial answer since every computable function is continuous; maybe you want to add the requirement that $f$ be continuous at least?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Certainly an *analytic* function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ is continuous (as in part 2.), but if you could elaborate on why *pointwise computable* (as in part 1.) implies continuity, I would find that a helpful Answer.

Comment: @hardmath my point was that any computable function is continuous - so, any non-continuous pointwise computable function would provide a counterexample to (1) as originally written - say, the characteristic function of the computable complex numbers.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I changed the wording of my first question when I realized this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes: it's easy to show that there are distinct continuous functions $f, g$ such that

- the domain of $f$ and $g$ is $D=\{a+bi: a, b\in[0, 1]\}$,
- on the boundary of $D$, $f$ and $g$ are zero, and
- $f(Q), g(Q)\subseteq Q$ (where $Q=\{a+bi: a, b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$).

Now say that a function $h$ is a *quilt* if it is gotten by pasting together copies of $f$ and $g$: that is, for every pair of integers $u, v$, we have $$h\upharpoonright \{a+bi: a\in [u, u+1], b\in [v, v+1]\}=T_{u, v}\circ f\circ T^{-1}_{u, v}$$ or $$h\upharpoonright \{a+bi: a\in [u, u+1], b\in [v, v+1]\}=T_{u, v}\circ g\circ T^{-1}_{u, v}$$ where $T_{u, v}$ is the translation taking $0$ to $u+vi$.

Since $f\not=g$, there are uncountably many quilts, and since $f(Q), g(Q)\subseteq Q$, every quilt is pointwise computable. But there are only countably many computable functions.

---

I believe the answer to (2) is also yes, but I don't have a proof yet; let me sketch why I think there is such a function.

Basically, we'll write $f$ as the limit of a sum of analytic functions: $$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nt_i(x).$$ We will of course have to guarantee that this limit converges, and that will take work - in particular, this is the part I'm least confident can be patched. For now, I'll ignore it.

Each $t_i$ will have a computable Taylor series (that is, a Taylor series whose coefficients form a computable sequence of rational numbers). Additionally, at stage $s$ in the construction, we will have fixed finitely many rational complex numbers $q_1, . . ., q_s$ and placed *requirements* on them of the form

- $R_1:\quad$ $\vert f(q_1)-\sum_{i=1}^s t_i(q_1)\vert<\epsilon_1$,
- $R_2:\quad$ $\vert f(q_2)-\sum_{i=1}^s t_i(q_2)\vert<\epsilon_2$,
- etc.

So basically, a stage in the construction is a pair $P_s=(t_1, t_2, . . . , t_s; R^{P_s}_1, R^{P_s}_2, . . . , R^{P_s}_s)$. There is a natural sense in which an analytic $t_{s+1}$ "makes sense" to tack onto $P_s$: each $\sum_{i=1}^{s+1}t_i(q_k)$ must satisfy $R_k$.

If we proceed in the natural way now, we obviously build a computable function. So the question is: how do we put a twist on this construction so that the resulting function is pointwise-computable-on-a-dense-set, but not computable?

The answer is **finite injury**. Basically, we want to construct a sequence of stages $(P_s)_{s\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that

- $\sum t_s$ is analytic, and
- for each $n$ there are only finitely many $s$ such that $P_{s+1}$ violates $R^{P_s}_n$.

Any such sequence of stages will correspond to an analytic function which is pointwise-computable-on-a-dense-set.

At this point we can diagonalize against the computable complex functions in the standard way: wait until the $0$th computable function makes a decision about where the $0$th rational should go, then injure the construction so far to make the $0$th computable function distinct from the $f$ we are building. (In fact, we can set this part up so that each requirement is injured at most once.)

Answer (score 0):

Noah Schweber seemed unsure about their approach to your second question, so I will give you the solution I found (which adapts Noah's work). Let $n\mapsto q_n$ denote any injective enumeration of the set of computable numbers, define $R_n=2^n+\max\{|q_j| : j\leq n\}$, and then define the functions $t_n$ as follows (where in the case $n=0$, the empty product is resolved to equal $1$).
$$t_n(x) = 2^{-n}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{x-q_j}{R_n}$$

Now, for any set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, let $f_S(x)=\sum_{n\in S}t_n(x)$. Our intent is to prove that $f_S$ is a well defined analytic function, that each $f_S$ is computable on a dense set (in fact, computable for all computable inputs), and that the map $S\mapsto f_S$ is injective. Since there are uncountably many $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, but only countably many computable functions, then almost every $f_S$ will be a non-computable function, which decides your second question.

---

There are three critical observations to make about the $t_n$ functions. Firstly, each $t_n$ is a computable function, namely an $n$'th degree polynomial with computable coefficients. Secondly, $t_n(q_j)=0$ if and only if $j<n$. Thirdly, when $x$ is restricted to some bounded neighborhood, we can use big-O notation to approximate $t_n(x) = O(2^{-n})$. To prove our third claim, take any $j<n$ and notice that $|\frac{x-q_j}{R_n}|\leq \frac{|x|}{2^n}+1$ and consequently $|t_n(x)|\leq 2^{-n}(1+|x|2^{-n})^n$. Because $|x|2^{-n} = O(2^{-n})$, which tends to zero with large $n$, then also $\ln(1+|x|2^{-n}) = O(2^{-n})$, which now implies $(1+|x|2^{-n})^n = \exp(O(n2^{-n})) = 1+O(n2^{-n})$. Since we had $|t_n(x)|\leq 2^{-n}(1+|x|2^{-n})^n$, it follows that $t_n(x)$ is bounded by $O(2^{-n})$ as required.

Relying on the third observation above, we quickly infer that each $f_S$ is a well defined analytic function. Indeed, $f_S(x)$ is bounded in magnitude by the sum $\sum_n |t_n(x)|$, and because we had $|t_n(x)|=O(2^{-n})$ when $x$ is bounded, then $f_S(x)$ converges by comparison to a geometric series. In fact, because the rate of convergence is bound independent of $x$, then this convergence is locally uniform, hence $f_S$ is a locally uniform limit of polynomials. Since polynomials are analytic, and a uniform limit of analytic functions is analytic, then each $f_S$ is analytic.

Now it's trivial to prove that $f_S$ is computable on a dense set. In fact, $f_S(q_j)$ is computable for all $j$, so that $f_S(x)$ is computable whenever $x$ is computable. Indeed, our second observation was that $t_n(q_j)=0$ whenever $n>j$, and so $f_S(q_j) = \sum_{n\in S} t_n(q_j) = \sum_{n\in S}^{n\leq j} t_n(q_j)$, proving $f_S(q_j)$ is a finite sum of computable numbers, which is computable.

Finally, we show that the map $S\mapsto f_S$ is injective. To do this, take any subsets $S,Z\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, and suppose $f_S=f_Z$, then we prove $S=Z$. In particular, we prove $k\in S \iff k\in Z$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. By contradiction suppose not, then let $k$ be the minimal counter example. Without loss of generality, suppose $k\in S$ and $k\notin Z$. As previously, we have $f_S(q_k)=\sum_{n\in S}^{n\leq k}t_n(q_k)$, with a similar identity for $f_Z$. Using this, we infer $f_S(q_k)-f_Z(q_k) = t_k(q_k)$, which holds via the minimality of $k$, since all the other terms in our sums cancel out. However, we had assumed $f_S=f_Z$ and thus $f_S(q_k)-f_Z(q_k)=0$, which now implies $t_k(q_k)=0$, contradicting our second observation about the construction of $t_k$. From this contradiction, it follows that $k\in S \iff k\in Z$, thus $S=Z$, hence the map $S\mapsto f_S$ is injective.